# Animate a UIButton from one image to another

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton

I noticed in the Jamie Oliver app, when you click one of the buttons, it goes from one size to another in a smooth transition. Does anyone know how this is done? I tried using some of the UIView animations, but none of them satisfies my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIAnimations alone can not give you that effect.. You need to couple them with transformations to achieve the effect that you are talking about. Try it in the following way. You will get what you need...

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Zoomin" context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
starImage.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.5, 2.5);
[UIView commitAnimations];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Zoomout" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
starImage.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Btw, do you know how/if I can actually change the image of the button while the animation is running?

Comment: you need to insert this code i the animation block...  [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

I believe [animation blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a) are the preferred method for animating views now.